# return value of a method

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a method that returns a NSMutableArray.. I am calling this method from another class and I would like to know how to put the returning NSMutableArray into a receiving object thats in the class thats called it.

**myClass.m**

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getMutableArray
{
    // Do some stuff

    return myMutableArray
}
```

**mycallingClass.m**

```
- (void)getMeMyMutableArray {

  // not really sure what to do here.. but something like.....

  // initialize class
  myClass *mc = [[myClass alloc] init];

  // call myClass method
  [mc getMutableArray]; // how do I get the returning value into a mutableArray in this class?
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense.. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMutableArray *myArray = [myClass getMutableArray];

Comment: or specifically since you named the instance "mc" NSMutableArray *myArray = [mc getMutableArray];

Comment: `getMutableArray` is an instance method, so it should be `NSMutableArray *myArray = [mc getMutableArray];` as you said.